# `std::filesystem::weakly_canonical` with special path parts fails

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

I have a path composed of some parts that end up containing special path parts `/../../` and to the right side some hypothetical parts. To left of the special parts the path can evaluate to a real path.
According to [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical) the hypothetical parts should be ok and not an issue in itself.

When passed to `std::filesystem::weakly_canonical` it fails due to being an invalid path (and not just a non-existent file/folder which should be ok). I guess this is because of the special parts `..` mentioned.

Is there anything I can call before passing to `weakly_canonical` to get the special parts handled ?

In reality i want to call `std::filesystem::make_relative` against another path - which in turn calls `weakly_canonical` on the input.

Comment: Can you please post an example of what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out this was due to the path being hypothetical after all (which could be a bug (?) ). I found out the solution was right in front of me, namely that `std::filesystem::path` has a function called `lexically_relative` which as the name implies doesn't use *external* calls.